# Constructing product automaton with conjunctive conditions

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

The question was to construct a DFA which accepts the language $$\{ x \in \{0,1\}^* \mid x\text{ starts with a }0\text{ and has at most one }1\}$$

So I first constructed DFA for '$x$ starts with a $0$' and a DFA for 'has at most one $1$' then I tried getting the product automaton of these, but the quiz says the automaton should not accept the string "" (empty string). Does that mean I just change $q_0p_0$ from accept state to normal state? or have I done something more wrong?

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/) is a nice online tool to design/draw/experiment with automata.

Comment: thanks that'll be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "DFA for 'has at most one $1$-symbol'" in the question is not correct. It accepts $101$, $0101$, etc.

The right one should be like the following.

[image: DFA that accepts strings with at most one 1, for cs150138. Made from http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/]

---

In the product automaton, you should label state $p_iq_j$ as accept state iff both $p_i$ and $q_j$ are accept states in their original automaton respectively, since the condition for string $x$ to be in the language is " ... *and* ...".

If the condition been "... or ...", then you should label state $p_iq_j$ as accept state iff at least one of $p_i$ and $q_j$ is an accept state in its original automaton.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, makes sense now, I didn't notice that it would accept more 1's.